# How to Convert to self created Entity Framework class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list, class, methods

I created a class with Entity Framework like this:

```
public class Lehrling
    {
       [Key]
       public int lehrling_id { get; set; }
       [Required]
       [StringLength(25)]
       public string vorname { get; set; }
       [Required]
       [StringLength(25)]
       public string nachname { get; set; }
    }
```

In my c# backend, i created a object of this class: `Lehrling lehrling = new Lehrling();` now, i want to assign a method to my object `lehrling` like this:

```
lehrling = dataMgr.GetLehrling(lehrlingID, requestedMd5key);
```

`lehrlingID` is type `int` and `requestedMd5key` is type `string`

The Method `GetLehrling(lehrlingID, requestedMd5key)` was created like this in my Datamanager.cs

```
public List<Lehrling> GetLehrling(int lehrlingID, string md5key)
        {
            Uri weburi = new Uri(baseuri, API_LEHRLING + lehrlingID + '/' + md5key);

            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync(weburi).Result;
                var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                List<Lehrling> data = ser.Deserialize<List<Lehrling>>(json);

                //Für Sortierung Wichtig

                return data;

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;

            }
        }
```

as you can see it returns a `List<Lehrling>` `data`
The Reason why i get a [image: error] message is clear, the method is type `List<Lehrling>` and the variable `lehrling` is type `Lehrling`

How can I fix this Error, any suggestions?

Comment: `lehrling = dataMgr.GetLehrling(lehrlingID, requestedMd5key).First();`? But what if you get multiple items in the list?

Comment: I am not sure where are using Entity Framework, and I am not sure what in general are you trying to do. why don't you just take the first item from the list?

Comment: i added a ss of the error message @arash.zh

Comment: entity framework code first creates my db. i need to assign the method to the lehrling object @gilmishal

Comment: Well, do you need to retrieve all of "lehrling"s as a list or do you need one? If you need a list `Lehrling lehrling = new Lehrling();` needs to be `List<Lehrling> lehrling = new List<Lehrling>();` if you need only 1 "lehrling" you should kinda go for `lehrling = dataMgr.GetLehrling(lehrlingID, requestedMd5key).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: i need to get multiple items from the list Lehrling @uteist

Comment: can you but your comment in a "real" answer, it worked, i can mark it as best answer so other people see too  @uteist

Comment: I just did it already. Changed `lehrling` to `lehrlingList` btw.

Comment: thats even better, very helpful thx @uteist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you said you actually need multiple items:

```
    Lehrling lehrling = new Lehrling();
```

Needs to be

```
    List<Lehrling> lehrlingList = new List<Lehrling>();
    lehrlingList = dataMgr.GetLehrling(lehrlingID, requestedMd5key);
```

That should eliminate the error.

Comment: well, now i get an errormessage, in my function. see above.... The errormessage sais invalid json primitive in catch(exception).. any idea why?

Comment: Well, that, I believe, is a new question. You are probably having issue with Deserializing your json data `List<Lehrling> data = ser.Deserialize<List<Lehrling>>(json);` According to error message, my best guess would be that there is something wrong with your json data. But I'm not experienced with `JavaScriptSerializer` usage tbh.

Answer (score 1):

You should choose an item from collection.

```
lehrling = dataMgr.GetLehrling(lehrlingID, requestedMd5key).FirstOrDefault(l => some codition);
```

Or just take first one.

```
lehrling = dataMgr.GetLehrling(lehrlingID, requestedMd5key).FirstOrDefault();
```

Both variant may lead to `NullPointerExeption` if no items were in collection.

Comment: This will not work, `Where` returns an `IEnumerable`. You probably meant `FirstOrDefault(l => some codition)`